# For how long a poisoned edge/surface would remain poisoned?

Tags: weapons, poisons

Background info:
Imagine a desert tribe of natives are preparing for an invasion from a big threat (highly developed civilization, or a big monster). They have access and knowledge of poisonous flora, and use those same substances to hunt and battle (like curare). But something happens and the conflict is avoided peacefully, so the tribesmen stow their poisoned weapons inside their homes, in a basket or hanging somewhere, ready to use if needed. Dry, protected from the sun and wind, but not refrigerated/conserved by our standards.

For how long the edges of blades, spears, arrows, darts, traps, etc. would remain poisoned? When they would need to reapply the poison? When they would be "safe enough" to use those once-poisoned weapons for rituals and sports/training?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a biology question? The lifespan of a poison would vary depending on the substance used. It's like asking how long a piece of string is.

Comment: This seems highly dependent upon the poison and the amount applied to the surface. How long do you need the weapons to remain poisoned?

Comment: It *totally* depends on the poison and how it's kept. Arsenic will keep forever in reasonable conditions. Most organic poisons will either oxidise with time or be degraded by ultraviolet light (the preparation of some poisons involves lacquering the arrows with protective, opaque "paint"). All hydrosoluble organics will be eventually washed away by rain, and so on.
Also, basically to be effective the poison has to *detach* from the weapon and enter the organism. The easier this detachment is, the more potent the poison... and the more fragile.

Comment: @NepeneNep I really don't know. It's not about the actual existing poisons we have now, just based off of them. Would be better if I deleted this post and created another one there?

Comment: @LSerni It is from plants. Plants can't produce arsenic naturally, they must at best extract from the soil if there is any, and arsenic poisoning is chronic, not acute, so this would be ill suited for combat uses.

Comment: @sphennings not how long, as I don't know this information. I know they "were" poisoned to be used in a coming conflict, but I lack the knowledge of time-degradation of plant-based poisons.

Comment: @RodrigoCns as no-one has answered your question yet, you can feel free to edit it and make sweeping changes. I feel that your question would be better phrased as "_how could I make a fast-acting plant-derived neurotoxin remain deadly on a weapon after a year of storage?_" or perhaps "_what is the best way to protect and store X such that it will remain rapidly deadly for as long as possible?_" Such questions have much more constrained answer domains, and don't require people to enumerate a bunch of wildly different possibilities in order to write a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Years.**

First, let us assume the plant toxin.  We will assume aconite.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aconitum

Aconite has alkaloids that kill by producing heart arrythmias.  People die to this day from aconite but usually ingestions now.  The ancient Greeks used aconite to poison weapons and various native people also used aconite poisoned weapons to hunt big animals including bears and whales.

[Aconite arrow poison in the old and new world](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/24530304.pdf)

Aconite was (and is some places is!) used as medicine.  I think people were looser about shelf stability in earlier times so I could not find hard info for a dried preparation.

I did find data for digitalis which is also a cardiotoxic plant alkaloid and I think similar enough for the extrapolation.

[Stability of digoxin tablets collected from U.S. hospitals](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/7325170/)

> The stability of digoxin tablets that had been stored in hospitals
> across the United States was studied. All hospital pharmacies in the
> U.S. were contacted in February 1980 to inform them about the
> program...Ninety-two samples, representing three manufacturers and an
> adequate cross-section of the country, as well as typical dosage forms
> and packaging variations, were selected for laboratory analyses of
> content uniformity, strength, dissolution, identification, and related
> fluorescing substances. Eighty-five samples met the current compendial
> standards and seven samples failed the dissolution specifications. All
> seven were manufactured before July 1975 when the UPS dissolution
> requirements were changed. The digoxin products studied were not
> adversely affected by the variable stresses of the marketplace.

All of these samples were 5 years old or older and 93% passed the quality tests.  I found it interesting that hospitals would have tablets on the shelf that were over 5 years old.  Different times.

I think you can extrapolate from the digitalis to aconite poisoned weapons.  Alkaloids are pretty stable.  If the weapons were wrapped up and kept in the dark and dry they should stay poisonous for years.

Comment: That's the answer I was looking for! 
I just undeleted the post because of it!